# I Can't Auto-Adjust The Banner

Tags: html, css, banner

The width is auto-adjusting but if I set height to anything but a px amount, the banner disappears. I've played around with min-height and overflow but the only thing that matters is having a px amount for height.

Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="banner"></div>
<style>
#banner {
    background:url('.png');

    width:100%;
    height:192px;
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;      
}
</style>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Without context, it's difficult to know what's going on.

Comment: The parent element containing your `#banner` needs to have a defined height for a percentage-based height to work. If you explain why a px amount is insufficient, we can try to come up with alternatives, but we need more context and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign a height to the html and body tags, then make your div height 100%, as follows:

```
<style>
html,body
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#banner {
background:url('.png');
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-size:100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;      
}
<style>
```

Comment: Brilliant, Atrix. Do you know why it would create a huge margin underneath the banner?